# django - current/request user is not passed in the template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-1.6

I have a model (`class Explore`) that has a GenericForeignKey relation with other classes. In that I have a method (`get_renedered_html`) to render the objects in a template (`explore_photo.html`) so that I can call the explore objects directly in the main template (`index.html`). But I can't get the request/current `user` object in the `explore_photo.html` only the object's user. However I can get the current/request `user` object in the main template (`index.html`).

I tried this in the `explore_photo.html`:

```
<p>{{ object.user }}</p><p>{{ user }}</p>
<p>{{ object.user }}</p><p>{{ request.user }}</p>
```

It only gives me the object's user and not the current/request user.

To check in the main template i.e. `index.html` I tried this:

```
<body>
    <p>Current user: {{ user }}</p>
    <h1>Explore</h1>
</body>
```

And it does, provide the current user object in the main template. What may be the cause? Or is it that I cant provide current user object to the `explore_photo.html' template? Please help me solve this problem. I would really appreciate it. Thank you!

This is my Explore model:

```
class Explore(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type','object_id')

    def get_rendered_html(self):
        template_name = 'explore_photo.html'
        return mark_safe(render_to_string(template_name, {'object': self.content_object}))
```

explore_photo.html:

```
{% if object.display == 'P' or user == object.user %}
<div class="explore_photo">
    <img src="media/{{ object.image }}">
    <p class="photo_date">{{ object.pub_date|date:"F jS Y, P" }}</p>
    <p class="photo_description">{{object.description}}</p>
    <p class="photo_user">{{ object.user }}</p>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

index.html:

```
<body>
    <p>Current user: {{ user }}</p>
    <h1>Explore</h1>
    <div id="explore">
        {% for photo in photos %}
            {{ photo.get_rendered_html }}
            <hr>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</body>
```

**Update:**

```
def explore(request):
    photos = Explore.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'photos':photos})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not using a RequestContext in the sub-template - and you won't be able to, because you would need to pass the request into the `get_rendered_html` method, but you can't pass parameters into methods from the template.

You should rewrite this as a [custom inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) which can automatically take the context and render the template:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('explore_photo.html', takes_context=True)
def explore(context, obj):
    return {'user': context['user'], 'object': obj.content_object}
```

and call it in the template:

```
{% load my_template_tags %}
...
    {% for photo in photos %}
        {% explore photo %}
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `'django.core.context_processors.request',` in your `settings.py`

#### example

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.tz',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
```

Comment: I don't have `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in my settings!!! I am using django 1.6. Do I have to add all of it then?

Comment: nope - that's all. I too use dj1.6 and double checked it again.